# Building a people search website

Tags: php

I want to do a project for my class that does a people search. I should be able to search into google, Facebook, twitter etc and display information about it. For example, I want to replicate what www.pipl.com does. What would be the best place to start with ? How can you do it ? Any specific/general responses, links or examples are most welcome. Thanks.

EDIT:
As this is being voted to close I thought I would be more specific. How can I write a wrapper class (or something of that sort) to mine an website for the information I want?

P.S. I've been a C/C++/java programmer till now and have a strong desire to learn new programming languages. Please feel free to redirect the question or to add tags so other users can also look at the questions.

Comment: Best place to start? See if any of those sites you mentioned have a decent API - which would make your life much easier.

Comment: Some of the popular one's would but most of them don't, right ? I want it to be scalable, like keep adding websites as I want them to be searched for.

Comment: APIs aren't all the same, so you'll have to write a new class/plugin with each site that you want to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" action="GET" name="search">
    <p>
        <label for="name">First &amp; Last Name:</label>
        <input name="q" id="name" />
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="searchBtn" value="Search" /></p>
</form>

<script>
document.forms['search'].addEventListener('submit', function() {
    // Add quotes around person's name (so that only their exact name matches)
    document.getElementById('name').value = '"'+document.getElementById('name').value+'"';
}, false);
</script>
```

Voilà! Facebook, twitters, and social media are all displayed, no extra work necessary.